# Latin translation of "model"

Tags: contemporary-latin, new-latin, modern-life, technology

"model", when meaning "a pattern for imitation", is expressed by Latin **exemplum**, **exemplar**, **forma**, **proplasma**, according to the dictionary. "model" comes from **modulus**, which means "measure" and I think inappropriate.

However, I am looking for an exact word for "model" in technical contexts (i.e. a system using mathematical/statistical methods for data manipulation and prediction), e.g.

> climate *model* (climate simulation system)
> language *model* (what GPT is)